# How to create a Drop down list from one table if cells contain particular String?

Tags: excel, vba

Requirement: Only cells which contain a particular string should be reflected in the drop down list (the last row number of the table may vary from system to system, so I cannot freeze the range although the sheet number for the table is fixed which is 2 and the column is A or 1 ).

```
Private Sub sEplan_Macro()
Dim i, s_count, sRow_number, Rnum As Integer
Dim s_itemsearch As Range
Dim FDarray() As Variant
Rnum = FormVariables.sRowNum
i = 0
Do While i < Rnum - 1

    If Cells(2 + i, 11).Value = "N" And Cells(2 + i, 12).Value = "Y" And _
      Cells(2 + i, 13).Value = "N" And Cells(2 + i, 10).Value = "2-wire" And _
      Cells(2 + i, 5).Value = "WORD" And Cells(2 + i, 6).Value = "IN" Then

        '*//This is the new added part which is creating issues*
        sRow_number = 1                     
        s_count = 0
        Do
            DoEvents
            sRow_number = sRow_number + 1
            Set s_itemsearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(sRow_number, 1)
            If InStr(s_itemsearch, "One JB\2-wire\AI") > 0 Then
                s_count = s_count + 1
            End If

            '*//Array to store the values from cells which contains the string*
            FDarray(s_count) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(sRow_number, 1).Value   
        Loop Until s_itemsearch = " "      *//Till here is the new part*

        '*//The part below used to create drop down list was working fine until modified*
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2 + i, 14).Validation          
            .Delete                                                                
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _           
               Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=FDarray                                 
            '*//Values of array is passed here*
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With

    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Rnum = 0
End Sub
```

This is the portion I am struggling with.

```
Dim s_count, sRow_number As Integer
Dim s_itemsearch As Range
Dim FDarray() As Variant

sRow_number = 1                     
s_count = 0
Do
    DoEvents
    sRow_number = sRow_number + 1
    Set s_itemsearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(sRow_number, 1)
    If InStr(s_itemsearch, "One JB\2-wire\AI") > 0 Then
        s_count = s_count + 1
    End If

    ' "Array to store the values from cells which contains the string"
    FDarray(s_count) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(sRow_number, 1).Value   
Loop Until s_itemsearch = " "
```

Comment: What `FormVariables` wants to be?

Comment: I try to understand what your code must do, but I'm afraid I cannot. In VBA, in order to comment a line, use "'" not "*//". Your first loop will be continue (if it works). You need to increment `i = i + 1`. `If` must end with `End If`. When condition will be true, you must use `Exit Do` in order to keep the result of first occurrence. I asked you about `FormVariables` and you do not say anything. How somebody will help you in those conditions...?

Comment: Hi. Formvariables is a module where I have declared variables which can be globally used.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have edited the question a bit, I hope this will provide clarity about the issue. Sorry for late response.

Comment: use single quote for commenting a line ( ' ). At what line of code does the error appear and which is its number/description?

Comment: ok. Thank you, I shall take care of it next time. The code shows Run-time error '1004' : Application-defined or object-defined error for line 
s_itemsearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(sRow_number, 1).Value

Comment: Did you test my code?

Comment: In your code `s_itemsearch ` is a range (an object) and cannot be = " ",  but it is not good to set each cell as a range. Try please my code and try to learn something from it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please:

```
Dim FDarray() As Variant, rngArr As Variant, k As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, El As Variant

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2): Debug.Print sh.Name
lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

rngArr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)' array which keeps all A:A range with data
ReDim FDarray(0)
For Each El In rngArr 'averything works in memory and fill the FDarray
    If InStr(El, "One JB\2-wire\AI") > 0 Then
        FDarray(k) = El: k = k + 1: ReDim Preserve FDarray(k)
    End If
Next
ReDim Preserve FDarray(k - 1) 'eliminate the last empty element (last k)
MsgBox UBound(FDarray) & " elements in the array, first of them is """ & FDarray(0) & """."
```

It will return the array elements number (starting from 0) and its first element.
Please confirm that it works for you, too.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. This served my purpose.